# Bosch Performance No charge?

Tags: battery, charging

Hi I have a 2017 Bosch equipped Cannondale Cointreau e it's the performance class 3 Bosch Drive. 500 battery. I'm getting 5 volts at the charger 120 volts going into the charger 5 volts on the output. No indication on the battery connections look clean bike turns on but no headlight and no assist. Tried charging on and off the bike battery removed battery installed. No indication whatsoever on the battery and no flashing charging on the display.

Comment: If the battery was original, its 5 years old.  How many charge cycles has it been through?  Does the Cannondale battery BMS track total charges and shut off at 500 or 1000 ?

Comment: There is often light on the charger. Does it change the color (usually green to red) when you connect the battery?